# functional equation for adelic theta function

Tags: number-theory, harmonic-analysis

The following is taken from p. 53 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.04265.pdf

[image]

I understand how $\gamma_{\mathbb{A}}(x)$ is invariant under Fourier transform, but I don't see how we get $1/x$ in the functional equation or the $1/|x|$  factor.

Comment: The Fourier series on $\Bbb{R/Z}$ : $\sum_{n\in \Bbb{Z}} e^{-\pi |(n+t) x|^2}=\sum_{k\in \Bbb{Z}} |x|^{-1} e^{-\pi |k/x|^2} e^{2i\pi kt}$ has an equivalent Fourier-Pontryagin series on $\Bbb{A_Q/Q}$. Replace $\{ e^{2i\pi kt},k\in \Bbb{Z}\}$ by the orthonormal basis (of characters) of $L^2(\Bbb{A_Q/Q})$ which is $\{\psi(kt),k\in \Bbb{Q}\}$ where $\psi$ is any fixed character. The $|x|^{-1}$ comes from $\langle e^{-\pi |t x|^2}, \psi(kt)\rangle$

Comment: @reuns Thank you but your comment is at too high a level for my current understanding. I think what I need is a simple calculus 1 type calculation shown/asked of me - is it that I have to compute the Fourier transform of $e^{-\pi(n+t)x}$ - so i can see the change of variables is happening

Comment: It is low level, not high level ! Fourier series : $\sum_{n\in \Bbb{Z}} e^{-\pi |(n+t) x|^2}=\sum_{k\in \Bbb{Z}} c_k e^{2i\pi kt}$ where $c_k=\int_{\Bbb{R/Z}}\sum_k e^{-\pi |(k+t)x|^2} e^{-2i\pi kt}dt=\int_{\Bbb{R}} e^{-\pi |tx|^2} e^{-2i\pi kt}dt=|x|^{-1} e^{-\pi |k/x|^2}$. Every step/term translates to $\Bbb{A_Q/Q}$, the main point is that we need a set of characters which is an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\Bbb{A_Q/Q})$. Then we take $t=0$ and we get your Poisson summation formula.

Comment: @reuns ah ok I can now understand your first comment and agree now it's low level. The key for me was the $c_k$ integral you wrote - I still have to do the integral - i think i've done it before. Thanks.